How to render with the Workbench settings as if it were a screenshot
I'd like to use some cameras to render images with the same settings as the workbench, effectively just using them to take a screenshot. Is there a way to do this?
I'm completely new to rendering so I don't really know anything about it but I've found that the render engine can be set to 'workbench' and the settings copied manually from the workbench.
However this doesn't give the same output as a screeshot. The background is not the same color and the lighting doesn't seem to be all there either since the highlights are not as bright.

Is there a way to take those settings into account or just straight up use the several cameras to take screenshots without rendering?
Any tutorials I've found about it are like 7 years old for the really old version of blender where nothing looks the same.


To render the Workbench/Viewport shading image, go to View > Viewport Render Image/Animation.

I'm going to try this with your file, not sure if it works perfectly with multiple cameras, but this is the only simple solution to render the viewport with wireframe.

I've tried that but it doesn't seem to be right either. The background is the same at least but the highlights don't do the same. It doesn't work with multiple cameras as far as I can see

Three things:
1. Change OpenEXR-RGBA to PNG-RGB


2. In the Render section adjust Color Management:
Color Management > View Transform > Row

It will give you this result :


3. Plus in Color Management edit Exposure to your taste.
E.g., with exposure set to 0.4 the scene looks this way :


NOTE: Color Management could be adjusted indefinite times not only before - but even AFTER the render is done (no need to re-render to try different settings)

About multiple cameras:
To render multiple cameras at once you can use Output > Stereoscopy > Multi-View
For new versions of blender it's comprehensively explained in this 3min video: =link=

